# Why doesn't the hagadah discuss miracles?

Tags: passover-seder-hagada, yetziat-mitzrayim, miracle, plagues-makkos

The hagadah (based on the discussion of Rav and Shmuel in pesachim) dedicates the bulk of maggid to expounded the verses of arami oved avi. But why is there very little discussion of the actual miracles (mainly the plagues) that took place as part of the exodus? We only have passing mentions of the plagues with no elaboration or additional midrashic material offered.

This stands in contrast to other holidays such as chanukah or purim where the focus is on the miraculous nature of divine salvation. Furthermore it seems to undermine the nature of the chag as a conduit from one generation to the next (v'higadeta l'bincha). Children are excited by miraculous tales by nature yet we seem to go out of our way to avoid talking these miracles in the hagadah. Why?

Comment: but we do! why do we dip twice? so the children will ask why we dip twice. or from the other position, if the miracles are not part of how the bond was formed, why include them at all?

Comment: Are you kidding??? #purimtorah?

Comment: @SethJ who me? not at all

Comment: "We were slaves to Pharaoh in Egypt, and the L-rd, our G-d, took us out from there with a strong hand and with an outstretched arm."

Comment: "The L-rd took as out of Egypt with a strong hand and an outstretched arm, and with a great manifestation, and with signs and wonders."

Comment: "The L-rd took us out of Egypt," not through an angel, not through a seraph and not through a messenger. The Holy One, blessed be He, did it in His glory by Himself!

Comment: DeTzaCh (blood, frogs, lice);
ADaSh (beasts, pestilence, boils);
BeAChaV (hail, locust, darkness, first-born).

Comment: Rabbi Yosi the Gallilean said: How do you know that the Egyptians were stricken by ten plagues in Egypt, and then were struck by fifty plagues at the sea?

In Egypt it says of them, "The magicians said to Pharaoh `This is the finger of G-d.' At the sea it says, "Israel saw the great hand that the L-rd laid against Egypt; and the people feared the L-rd, and they believed in the L-rd and in His servant Moses."

Now, how often were they smitten by `the finger'? Ten plagues!

Thus you must conclude that in Egypt they were smitten by ten plagues, at the sea they were smitten by fifty plagues!

Comment: And on and on and on....

Comment: now i have to ask if you are kidding! the pesukim you quote are not expounded to have anything to do with the makkot or the miracles in mitzrayim at all. and my question is exactly on r' yosi haglili; how is that the only mention of the miracles in mitzrayim?! there is no explanation of each makkah, we don't employ any of the myriad midrashim to describe what happened and how everything was so miraculous. Instead we simply add up the numbers and focus the bulk of magid on arami oved avi. we've been so conditioned since childhood to believe we discuss the miracles but in fact we never do!

Comment: @Moshe what "bulk of magid"?  Count the words, they get equal treatment.

Comment: @avi et al. perhaps you can help me rephrase this question because I don't think it is coming across properly. Can we all agree that in the hagadah the DISCUSSION is not focused on the miracles of the plagues? I agree we MENTION them but what we actually EXPOUND on are the pesukim of arami oved avi (as per the halacha in the rambam). my question is why is this so conceptually.

Comment: @Moshe  The hagadah has many sections.  A paragraph stating that we were slaves in Egypt etc, a section about the need to study, an analysis of arami oved avi, an alaysis of the 300+ plagues, an analaysis of matzah marror pesach for the seder, and then we eat.  Each section is given roughly the same amount of focus and words.

Comment: @Moshe Ok, after answering your initial question more thoroughly, I think I realized what your actual question might be.  Are you asking why we analyze the paragraph read by the baal habayit while giving over his Bikurim, instead of analyzing the section of the Torah which describes the events in Egypt?  Cause that is a very different question, but might be better related to what you are asking.

Comment: @Moshe, how do you not consider it "expounding on the miracles in Egypt and the plagues" by the one-upsmanship in counting and multiplying how many plagues there were, both in Egypt and at the sea (for just one example)? How is it not expounding on the miracles by comparing "outstretched arm", etc., to other verses that greatly expand upon that imagery? That _is_ Midrash!

Comment: @SethJ maybe I have a different definition of expounding but I would take expounding to mean describing in more thorough detail. showing that there were more than 10 makkos doesn't convey any new information about what the makkos were and what their impact was. As such it doesn't provide the child we are trying to educate with any meaningful way to relate to the material. there is just more of this still vague concept of makkah.

Comment: @Moshe So are you asking why we don't go into detail about each makkah and bring the midrashim about it?  I mean not much "new and exciting" information is mentioned about eved aram avi either...  I'm really confused now about what you are asking.

Comment: Moshe, when you figure out what you want to ask, please work it into the body of the question. I'm closing this as a temporary, not because it's a bad question, but because it doesn't clearly ask what you mean for it to ask, so any answers you get now will not be what you seek. Once the question asks what you mean it to, it can be reopened (and these comments can be deleted).

Comment: Moshe, I do hear what you are saying, but I agree with @msh210 that it is not being conveyed in the question. Can you try to tighten it up? (I know, ironic coming from me, given last night's botched question, but we live and learn.)

Answer (score 2):

I believe you need to take a look at the Hagadah again.

I'm using the hagadah found here, and using the word count feature of word:

http://207.232.9.131/moe/hagut/pesach/download/haggadah.rtf

The section where the Hagadah speaks about  "arami oved avi" uses about 265 words to explain the passages, until it gets to the part where the Jewish people were saved by Hashem.

It then uses 300 words, to describe how god and not an angel rescued us, and took us out with an outstretched arm.  While this section does not describe the plagues directly, it does speak about god rescuing us the miracles.

The hagadah continues with enumerating the plagues using another 246 words.

All in all, I'd say the treatment is about equal.

However, the hagadah also has a ritual related to the plagues which does not exist in recounting the earlier history.

Comment: I want to give you a +1 for the points you are bringing, but you are not answering the question. This answer would best be brought in chat or the comments (the latter of which I know you've been doing).

Comment: The answer to his question is that we don't avoid talking about them, but rather give them equal treatment to other parts of the hagadah.

Comment: @SethJ oops, forgot to tag.